# Literature Request: Where to find the formula for the sum-of-squares function?

Tags: number-theory, reference-request

I'm desperately searching for a reference to the formula

$$
r_2(n) := \# \{(x,y) \in \mathbb Z^2 \mid x^2 + y^2 = n\} =  4 \sum_{\substack{d \mid n \\ d \text{ odd}}} (-1)^{\frac {d-1}2}
$$
As far as I know this can either be proved with some argument on prime factorization in $\mathbb Z[i]$ or with the class number formula. However, I can't find the above formula anywhere in Literature. Does anyone know a book I could cite for this?

Comment: Actually going to be more books in German on this. You can use Leonard Eugene Dickson, Introduction to the Theory of Numbers (about 1929). I will probably put as an answer once I have a page number.

Comment: Apparently you are missing a factor of 4

Comment: https://archive.org/details/in.ernet.dli.2015.466075/page/n89/mode/2up

Comment: @WillJagy Ah yes, of course.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Theorem 65 on page 80 of (Dover reprint). Introduction of the Theory of Numbers. by Leonard Eugene Dickson (original about 1929).

[image]

Here is the relevant text from the page, transcribed:

> ### Binary Quadratic Forms
>
> **51. Sum of two squares.** We apply Theorem 64 with $d = -4$ and $m$ any positive, odd integer. By (34) we may delete the factor $4$ from $(-4\mid \mu).$ We may take $x^2 + y^2$ as the single form in the representative system. For the case $k=0,$ we therefore have
>
> Theorem 65. *The number of all representations of $2^k m$ (where $m$ is positive and odd) by $x^2 + y^2$ is $4E,$ where $E = \sum(-1)^{\frac{1}{2}(\mu - 1)},$ summed for all positive divisors $\mu$ of $m.$ Hence $E$ is the excess of the number of divisors $\equiv1\pmod{4}$ of $m$ over the number of divisors $\equiv 3\pmod{4}$ of $m.$*
>
> Next, if $2n = x^2 + y^2,$ we have $x + y = 2X, x - y = 2Y,$ where $X$ and $Y$ are integers; whence $n = X^2 + Y^2.$ The correspondence between the pairs $x,y$ and $X,Y$ is one to one. This completes the proof of Theorem 65, which was first obtained by Jacobi in his *Fundamenta nova theoriae functionum ellipticarum* (1829).

Comment: In any case, posting a photo of a page from the book on a public site may be a copyright violation.

Comment: @mathguy   I would have made a scan, but I found a scanned version online, freely available https://archive.org/details/in.ernet.dli.2015.466075/page/n89/mode/2up

Comment: Thank You! Don't bother with the photo, I've found a suitable copy online.

Comment: @WillJagy I took the liberty of transcribing the text from the image into your answer so that future readers who found the image difficult to parse would be able to understand (especially if the links in the comments go down). Feel free to revert this if you'd rather not have it as part of your answer!

Comment: @Stahl   that's good. Easier reading than the page itself, I never noticed the Jacobi reference